# $U(n)$ consisting only prime numbers

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Let $U(n)$ be the set of all positive integers which are coprime to $n$ and less than $n$.

We see that $U(8) = \{1,3,5,7\}$. It is a good observation to see that $U(8)$ consists prime numbers except 1. One more example is $U(12)$.
I had many futile attempts to find such $n$ where $U(n)$ consists only primes except 1.

Is it true that there are finitely many $n$ such that $U(n)$ consists only primes except 1?

Comment: The largest is $n = 30$. Try to find a criterion, and then try to prove that $30$ is the largest integer satisfying that criterion.

Comment: See [OEIS:A048597](https://oeis.org/A048597). For a characterization of the numbers in the sequence and a proof, see [Schatunowsky's Theorem](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Schatunowsky%27s_Theorem).